# Lower Limit Prime Gap

Tags: number-theory

The recent result of Zhang states
$$
\lim \inf_{n\rightarrow \infty}(p_{n+1}-p_{n})<7\times 10^{7}
$$
The upper bound is being optimized but if we assume
$$
\lim \inf_{n\rightarrow \infty}(p_{n+1}-p_{n})<C
$$
where $2<C<7\times 10^{7}$. What does that imply about the structure
of prime numbers or in other words what will be the home take message for
prime gaps if the lower limit of the gap is not two?

Comment: You may want to try MathOverflow for this question. Some of the people compute C regularly post over there.

Comment: The Hardy-Littlewood conjectures predict that there are infinitely many twin primes. If the twin prime conjectures fail, it means that Cramer's model (together with the modification of leading term by local consideration) fails, and we probably need to model primes in other ways.

Comment: Still no reaction to bounty ...

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2015-52-02/S0273-0979-2015-01480-1/S0273-0979-2015-01480-1.pdf

Comment: That is still complicated ...

Comment: Yes, it is complicated. Try: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.2123.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are [overoptimistic](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoW_0NuaPj4). There is no guarantee that current methods will identify the $\color{magenta}{\liminf}.$ As any particular bound $C$ is proved, all that is certain is that at least one gap smaller than $C$ occurs infinitely often.

Comment: haha, awesome song and thanks for the reply.